# rails 3 best approach multiple apps within one app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, rails-engines

I have a rails 3 app that has 2 different UIs that both share the same model but have different UIs.  Lets call these retailers and customers "sites".  What is the best approach in rails 3 for creating a monolithic application to keep these two apps in one app.  Should I just namespace the controllers, and change routing as such?

namespace "retailers" do 
    resources :posts, :comments 
end

namespace "customers" do 
    resources :posts, :comments 
end

and place all the customer controllers in customers directory and likewise for retailers? and namespace the view directories as well?

Comment: If the only difference is the UI, can't you just use two different layouts?

Comment: these are being worked on by two different groups.  there are some controllers and forms in one that aren't in the other app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend putting the two different resources in separate namespaces.

In addition I would make two separate base controllers for retailers and customers, e.g. `RetailerController` and `CustomerController` and then make all respective controllers inherit from these.

You probably might want to put the customers into the root namespace, i.e. a regular customer could access your site at `http://myshop.com` but the retailers (who you probably can instruct better) would have to to go `http://myshop.com/retailers`